# angular custom table not able to render data from API

Tags: angular, api, angular-material, rendering

I created a custom table it's working well with mock data but with fetching data from API it's not even though data are shown in the console

I added detectchange and Onpush change but it not working

```
export class GenericTableComponent<T> implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  columns!: Column<T>[];
  @Input()
  rows!: Row<T>[];

  public dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Row<T>>();
  public columnNames: string[] = [];

  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataSource.data = this.rows;
    this.columnNames = this.columns.map((column) => column.name.toString());
  }
}

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
 datarow: Row<data>[] = [];
  fetchedData: Row<data>[] = [];
  Columns: Column<any>[] = [];
  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initializeColumns();
    this.userService.getusersById().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.content = data.body;
        this.content.forEach((element: any) => {
          this.datarow.push({
            values: {
              id: element.id,
              active: element.active,
              description_ar: element.description_ar,
            }
          })
        });
        this.cd.detectChanges();
        console.log(this.datarow);
      }
    );

  }

  initializeColumns(): void {
    this.Columns = [
      { name: 'id' },
      { name: 'active' },
      { name: 'description_ar' },
    ];

  }
```

Comment: Which version of angular-material are you using?

Comment: @Takatalvi version 11

Answer (score 0):

Solved By adding *ngif="data.length>0" to the table selector and this.detectChanges(); after getting data in typescript file